# Should I use "will" or "would" for a dream?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Which of these is better?

> "My dream was that I will go there"

Or

> "My dream was that I would go there"?

Comment: If the speaker still hasn't 'been there', it's logical to say "My dream **is** that I will go there".

Comment: I'm about a past time

Comment: The question style with two phrases an "which is correct" does not tend to invite answers that explain *why* and *how*.  Take another look at [ask].  Could you do anything to improve this question?]

Comment: Are you asking about a literal dream (in your sleep), or a figurative one (an ambition)?  That likely makes a big difference to the answer.

Comment: @Kate, only if still dreaming (and that likely depends whether it's a literal or a metaphorical dream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is more correct. If a person in the past is talking about the future, they use the past tense of will, or would.

Comment: 'More correct' assuming that the person had a dream in the past which may or may not have been achieved in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

My dream **is** that I **will go** there someday.

My dream **was** that I **would go** there someday.

Quite simply, that is the standard grammar here.